# Identity Increment in SQL Server object explorer is grayed out. How to set is identity = true in sql server object explorer in VS13?

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-2012

I am able to do this in SSMS. I want to do this in SSOE in VS13.

Comment: You should first change data type to INT, then it will be enabled. did you do that?

Comment: Yes, The data type is INT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

View the table in Designer mode, right click and try set identity. good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Things to check:

If table has already been created, SSMS is default-set to prevent changes like that (which actually drop and re-create the table behind the scenes). If this is the case with you, in SSMS go to Tools -> Options -> Designers -> uncheck "Prevent saving changes that require table re-creation"

If it's a new table (or you've already done the above), make sure the column in question is of type "int". By default, SSMS sets a new column (even one that ends with "ID") to be nchar(10), which can be misleading.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't set the primary key column as the identity in SSMS because the column had a default value. Removing the default value enabled setting the identity specification for me.

Answer (score 0):

if your value type doesnt "int" you cant set identity Specification